# Row comparison in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can You Please help me on this.

Driver table:

CAT Code Parttype       BasePartNo  LikePartNo
MCN  FLOORMAT  AEM2157   AEM2157**
MCN  FLRLNR      AEM444410  AEM4*4410

Build Part No Table

CAT Code,Parttype,     BasePartNo,LikePartNo1,LikePartNo2,LikePartNo3
MCN,       FLOORMAT, MCNW10,    MCNW10TN,  MCNW10GR,--ETC
MCN,        FLRLNR    ,  MCN444410, MCN454410, MCN464410-- ETC

Application Table

make, model,year, engine,   part#   class   line
9999, 9998,1776, 0  AEM21-2157  CLASS   AIRFILCOLD --This is the base part
80  9998    1776    0   AEM21-2157DK    BREAK   AIRFILCOLD--This is the likepart
56  9998    1776    0   AEM21-2157GE    TRAKE   AIRFILCOLD--This is the likepart
9999    9998    1776    0   AEM21-2057YL    CLASS   AIRFILCOLD--This is the likepart
79  9998    1776    0   AEM444410   DRAKE   AIRFILCOLD-This is the base 
79  9998    1776    0   AEM454410   DRAKE   AIRFILCOLD--This is likepart
79  0000    1776    0   AEM454410   DRAKE   AIRFILCOLD--This is likepart

Then the result should

80  9998    1776    0   NULL    AEM21-2157DK    BREAK   AIRFILCOLD
56  9998    1776    0   NULL    AEM21-2157GE    TRAKE   AIRFILCOLD
79  0000    1776    0   NULL    AEM454410   DRAKE   AIRFILCOLD

Base Part Attribute need to compare with Likepart attribute and if any change in attribute of likepart wrt base part attribute then it should come in output. Please Please help me.

likepart and basepart are control by driver and Build table.
and all comparison need to done in application table

Thanks again.
Your Buddy

Comment: Your question is not truly clear (na question ends with a '?'). I suggest you change your question, its pretty long and you can't expect everybody to expect read all this. Try to keep it short, and to the point...;-)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Did you try anyhting yet? If yes, show your code.

Comment: Thanks. what i need is comparison of columns like (make,model,desc..etc) for base part

Comment: @Rogier Thanks. what i need is comparison of columns like make,model,desc etc for base part to the comparison of columns like make,model,desc etc for likepart. both are in same table, and if changes in likepart column then it should appear in result

Comment: Any time you find yourself adding numbered columns to a table, it's usually a sign that your data model isn't correct - Is there a *logical* difference between a value appearing in `LikePartNo7` versus the same value appearing (in another row) in `LikePartNo33`? If not, it indicates that there should be a table where both of those values appear in the same column (but with other columns linking back to the original rows). If there is a logical difference, it's often better to still do this and have another column store the `7` or `33` value with an actual name that describes it.

Comment: Thanks @damien_The_Unbeliver, but i am not authorised to change in modelling, just i need to design query like make,model,year,engine,remarks,part#,class,line 9999,9998,1776,0,NULL,AEM21-2057,CLASS,AIRFIL,This is the base part 80,9998,1776,0,NULL,AEM21-2057DK,BREAK,AIRFIL This is are likepart 9999,9998,1776,0,NULL,AEM21-2057TR,CLASS,AIRFILThis is are likepart THEN OUTPUT LIKE 80,9998,1776,0,NULL,AEM21-2057DK,BREAK,AIRFIL AS Rows are not same with basepart.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using SQL Server